# Slack Dialog external data source filtering

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I have a Slack dialog that has two `SELECTs` and both are pulling data from an external data source. However, the available options of the second `SELECT` are entirely depending on the selected value of the first `SELECT`. Is it possible that slack can somehow pass the selected value of the first `SELECT` to the payload of the second `SELECT's` request?

I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this within a modal view, there are two ways to approach the problem:

- Approach 1: stick to 1 view and update it*:

- The user picks from list 1.
- This triggers a block action payload to your app which gives you access to their choice.
- You can then [update](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#updating_views) the view with new input blocks for list 2 that you've set up correctly.

The catch here is that list 1 can not be an *input* block, but rather an action. It will not be part of the final payload of the form.

- Approach 2: split into 2 different views*:

- The user picks from list 1.
- The user submits view 1
- You handle the view_submission event by [pushing](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#pushing_views) a new view with the appropriate list 2